# onActivityResult not called in Fragment only in Activity in scanning appl

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am new to Android. My scanning appl is not able to call onActivityResult  in fragment. I did check the other threads but unable to understand the issue.

```
public class BarCodeFrag extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment SearchCatFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static BarCodeFrag newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        BarCodeFrag fragment = new BarCodeFrag();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public BarCodeFrag() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

//    @Override
//    public void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int code) {
//        BarCodeFrag.startActivityForResult(intent, code);
//    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    //the custom view
    private SearchView myView;
    private Button scanBtn;
    private TextView formatTxt, contentTxt;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_barcode, container, false);

        //get reference to the custom view
//        myView = (SearchView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.androidATCView1);

        scanBtn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.scan_button);
        formatTxt = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.scan_format);
        contentTxt = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.scan_content);

        scanBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(v.getId()==R.id.scan_button){
                    //instantiate ZXing integration class
                    IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(getActivity());
                    //start scanning
                    scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
                   // startActivityForResult(scanIntegrator, 1888);

                }
                else{
                    //invalid scan data or scan canceled
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                }
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p/>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        //retrieve result of scanning - instantiate ZXing object
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode,  resultCode,  intent);
        IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        //check we have a valid result

        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Inside onActivityResult" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if (scanningResult != null) {
            //get content from Intent Result
            String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
            //get format name of data scanned
            String scanFormat = scanningResult.getFormatName();
            //output to UI
            formatTxt.setText("FORMAT: " + scanFormat);
            contentTxt.setText("CONTENT: " + scanContent);

            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Reply: " + scanFormat + ":" + scanContent, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            CheckAvailability(scanFormat);
        }}
```

I intend to see FORMAT and CONTENT from scan. This appl is working an an individual appl, but when I add the code in a fragment to add to my other app - I am unable to see FORMAT and CONTENT. Any suggestions are welcome. Many thanks.

Comment: Is your hosting activity using `onActivityResult` aswell? If so please make sure you call `super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,intent);`

Comment: Instead of passing `Activity` here: `IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(getActivity());`, try passing `Fragment` like this: `IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(BarCodeFrag.this);`

Comment: zozelfelfo - yes, it is being called too.     public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        //retrieve result of scanning - instantiate ZXing object
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode,  resultCode,  intent);

Comment: Rehan,  intendintegerator is expecting an activity.  public IntentIntegrator(Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
    title = DEFAULT_TITLE;
    message = DEFAULT_MESSAGE;
    buttonYes = DEFAULT_YES;
    buttonNo = DEFAULT_NO;
    targetApplications = TARGET_ALL_KNOWN;
    moreExtras = new HashMap<String,Object>(3);
  }

Comment: @Dep Did you try? Because I just confirmed the code of ZXing `IntentIntegrator` class and it has Constructor for `Fragment` too. If you can't call it, do confirm that you have the latest version integrated

Comment: Actually I am using a code from internet. I can try that too but need to figure out how to, not sure how will it help. can you pls elaborate on the issue? I am able to scan just displaying the result is a prob. Stuck in this prob for last 2 days.

Comment: @Dep Simply replace this line `IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(getActivity());` with `IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(BarCodeFrag.this);` in your code and then tell if it has any issue or does not resolve your problem

Comment: @Dep Normally when `onActivityResult` is not called in Fragments it is because when you start activity by `getActivity().startActivityForResult` instead of using `startActivityForResult` in `Fragment` simply. Here, as you are not starting it by yourself, ZXing should have handled it for you. To my knowledge, ZXing has already provided you two Constructors to avoid this issue. So it should work for you if you call the proper Constructor.

Comment: Rehan - I tried that but issue is my code do not have constructor for IntentIntegrator and intentintegerator.java (code I downloaded from internet) is doing all work using Activities.Simply replacing gives error that expected is Activity.

Comment: @Dep - Then you might have to look into your ZXing integration as you can check https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/android-integration/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentIntegrator.java on **Line Number: 166** that `IntentIntegrator` has separate Constructor for `Fragment`

Comment: Thanks Rehan, let me try this.

Comment: Tried this intentintegerator and also BarCodeFrag.this, but BarCodeFrag.this still gives error that a Fragment is expected coz I am using import android.app.Fragment; and not import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

Comment: Above problem solved by changing the Fragment class. I was using

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;

earlier, but changed to below:

import android.app.Fragment; import android.app.FragmentManager;

Now I am getting error: Error:(56, 61) error: inconvertible types required: NavigationDrawerFragment found: Fragment on below line

    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));